# Python bot does not read messages

Tags: python, discord, bots, audio-player

Whatever I do my bot simply refuses to read any messages. Messages do not appear in the run menu.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl 

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
intents.messages = True
intents.presences = True  # Enable the Presence Intent
intents.voice_states = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')
    print('------')

    print('Guilds (servers):')
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        print(f'- {guild.name} (id: {guild.id})')

@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()

@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client
    if voice_client:
        await voice_client.disconnect()

@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, *, query):
    voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client
    if not voice_client:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        voice_client = await channel.connect()

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(query, download=False)
        url = info['formats'][0]['url']

    voice_client.stop()
    voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url, before_options="-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5"))

@bot.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client
    if voice_client and voice_client.is_playing():
        voice_client.stop()

bot.run('MY TOKEN SHOULD BE HERE')
```

Messages should appear here but they are not
[image]

I gave my bot all the permissions in the Discord applications
there are no errors in the console or while debugging

Answer (score 0):

hope all is well.

In my personal experience, async print will not execute visibly if:

1. async function/method is not awaited
2. asyncio.run() is top level and your python version is greater than 3.7

```py
# your code goes here


def main() -> None:
    bot.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***if this doesnt work***

I would try:

1. edit the bot.command to apply await
2. write another decorator that auto awaits.
3. create a queue.Queue that loops over a queue with strings to print to the terminal.

```py
import queue 
import multiprocessing as mp
import atexit


TerminateFlag: str = "<Bye>"
TerminalQueue = mp.Queue()

def end_checker():
   global TerminalQueue, TerminateFlag
   
   try:    
       TerminalQueue.put(TerminateFlag)
   except:
       pass

def thread_queue_checker(queue: Queue.queue) -> None:
   
   global TerminateFlag

   atexit.register(end_checker)

   while True:

       if queue.empty() == False:

           if item == TerminateFlag:
               break
           
           item = queue.get()

           print(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   mp.frozen_support()

   check_process = mp.Process(target=thread_queue_checker, args=(TerminalQueue, ))
   check_process.run()
```